# Bouncing Ball With Gravity In Java

Tags: java, gravity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I apply gravity to my bouncing ball application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342189/how-do-i-apply-gravity-to-my-bouncing-ball-application)

I have a ball class that bounces off the ground.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
public void update(){
  yPos += ySpeed;
  ySpeed += gravity;

  if(yPos > BOTTOM_OF_SCREEN){
    ySpeed *= -1;
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that when I have a ball in mid air, it bounces higher than it started, and keeps bouncing higher and higher, but I want it to bounce to the same height that it started with.

Answer (score 3):

Do not increase the speed on hitting the bottom (only when it is falling free):

```
   void update() {
        yPos += ySpeed;

        if (yPos > BOTTOM_OF_SCREEN) {
            ySpeed *= -1;
        } else ySpeed += gravity;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the problem.

It turns out that I was using Eulers method of numerical integration, which has inaccuracies. In fact, the graph on [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) illustrates my problem.

So it turns out that I have to use a different method (like Verlet integration, which I'm currently trying).

Comment: There was a bug in your code, which I pointed out. Your question was not about realistic ball bouncing.